# Getting someone's attention in Campfire

Tags: chat, basecamp

According to [this help page](http://help.37signals.com/campfire/questions/249-how-can-i-get-someone-s-attention-in-a-crowded-chat-room), you can get someone's attention by starting a message with @. But I don't see what it does. What I want is similar to IRC - normal messages don't make a sound effect, but messages with someone's name do. Is that possible with Campfire?

Answer (score 1):

There's John Wood's Campfire plugin, which can do what you wish:

http://johnpwood.net/2011/03/26/custom-audio-notifications-in-campfire/

You can also play sounds on demand in Campfire by typing "/play bueller" or another one of the sounds listed here:

https://github.com/37signals/campfire-api/blob/master/sections/messages.md

Comment: I wanted to only alert one person though, not the whole room.